# What kind of hash does the VeraCrypt tool use?

Tags: encryption, hash

Whirlpool? SHA-512? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

Veracrypt is supporting multiple hash algorithms, which are listed in the [documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Hash%20Algorithms.html).

It supports the following Hash Algorithms:

- RIPEMD-160
- SHA-256
- SHA-512
- Whirlpool
- Streebog